proof: projecting a projective variety onto the first component remains a projective variety
I have recently begun studying algebraic geometry and have decided to start with Harris' classic, supplementing it with these online notes from a lecture, based on his book, given by Harris himself at Harvard in 2016. These lecture notes have turned out to be incredibly helpful in filling in the details, often missing in Harris' book.
Currently, I am working on the $11$th lecture of the course at Harvard (which, in turn, becomes lecture $3$ in the book), and have a question regarding the proof of Lemma $11.6$ of the lecture notes linked above. The claim reads:

Suppose $X \subset Y \times \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety and $\pi : Y \times \mathbb{P}^n \to Y$. Then, $\pi(X) \subset Y$ is a projective variety.

I reproduce the proof included in the lecture notes:

Proof. The idea is to use induction on $n$. The base case is Lemma $11.5$ [The statement for $n=1$ has already been shown]. We will choose a point $p \in \mathbb{P}^n$ and a hyperplane $H \cong \mathbb{P}^{n−1} \subset \mathbb{P}^n$. We consider the projection map
$$\eta:= \text{id}\times\pi_p  :Y\times (\mathbb{P}^n\setminus\{p\})\to Y\times \mathbb{P}^{n−1}$$
So, by induction, it suffices to show the following lemma.

Lemma 11.7. With notation as above, $\eta(X) \subset Y \times \mathbb{P}^{n−1}$ is a projective variety.

Proof. We’d like to just say the image of a projective variety is a projective variety. The only problem is that the variety can’t contain the point. However, it may be that the cross section $p$ intersects the variety $X$. This works away from the locus of points in $Y$ where $p$ intersects the fiber of $X$. That is, define
$$V = \{q \in Y : (q, p) \in X\}$$
This is a closed subvariety of $X$. We just restrict the equations defining $X$ to $Y × {p}$.
Note that $\pi(X)\cap Y\setminus V$ is closed in $Y\setminus V$ and $V\subset \pi(X)$. These together imply that $\pi(X)$ is closed in $Y$, but straightforward point set topology.



I have been able to work out all the details except for one: How can one show that $\pi(X)\cap Y\setminus V$ is closed in $Y\setminus V$? At first, I thought that this could be traced back to Lemma $11.1$ from the lecture notes, which basically asserts that the projection $\pi_p(A)\subset \mathbb{P}^{m-1}$ from a point $p$ of a projective variety $A\subset \mathbb{P}^m$ remains a projective variety. Yet in our setting, it is $\eta = id \times \pi_p$ we are dealing with, so Lemma $11.1$ cannot be applied directly. I tried adapting its proof to this case, but the Zariski topolgy on the product $Y\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ coming from Segre's embedding makes it too difficult.
Neither Harri's book, nor these lecture notes justify the claim that $\pi(X)\cap Y\setminus V$ is closed in $Y\setminus V$ yet it does not seem trivial to me. Am I missing something? Any hint is appreciated :D
